# Sync Chrome extensions that aren't in the web store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that's purely for personal use. I'd like it if it were synced to all my Chrome instances where I'm logged in. Is there a way to do this without putting it in the Web Store?
This thing is really personalized—it contains links to the websites I frequent and does some user-script-like tomfoolery, so it wouldn't make sense to make it publicly available by putting it in the Web Store.

Comment: Just pointing out you can still put it in the Web Store without making it public

Comment: Will it blend ? (I don't know - I haven't tried syncing. I am just pointing out the fact that "putting it in the Web Store" and "making it publicly available" are two different things.)

Comment: Less public extensions on the WB should still sync between computers.